# Who had Akkarin's third Blood Gem in the Black Magician Trilogy?

Tags: trudi-canavan, black-magician

In The Black Magician Trilogy, when introducing Sonea to the blood gems, Akkarin states that he has three blood gems.

- One is with Takkan
- One is with Lorlen
- "One with a friend in a useful place"

Canavan has stated that the observant reader should know who it is with, so who is it?

A quick google search hasn't revealed anything conclusive.

EDIT: It looks like the answer may be definitively revealed soon - Canavan is hosting [a competition on her blog](http://www.trudicanavan.com/2011/04/win-a-signed-hardback-first-edition-of-the-rogue/) with this exact question as the competition question.

Comment: Are both the 'b' and the 'g' in Blood Gems always capitalized or one and not the other?   I really don't know what the correct grammar rule is.

Comment: In my edition it appears they are neither capitalised, nor italicised. I do find this odd, seeing as they are in-world items, and I thought it was convention for them to be at least italicised.

Comment: <strike>It's with Ceryni of the Thieves. He obviously couldn't tell her, because that would fan the hell out of her paranoia.</strike>

Comment: @darius: I'm now pretty sure I'm wrong. I swear I remember him having it, but I can find no citation. Going forward from the point where he mentions it, I can't find anyone who he speaks to, or alludes to knowledge from, which would come from the ring.

Comment: My thought was that he was was in fact of possession of the Blood Gem but it's been a while ago that I can't remember where could I find it.

Comment: I wouldn't have thought it would have been Ceryni, as otherwise Akkarin would have known about the Ichani female who visited Ceryni.

Comment: @samuel: In my head, I remembered him knowing. But you're right, that was one of the things that made me think I was wrong. My later assumption was that he'd given it to the *King* because that would have been handy as hell, but I haven't found mention, yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is contained in The Rogue - the second book of the Traitor Spy Trilogy - sequel to The Black Magician Trilogy.

It wasn't someone who we could have guessed directly, but the short answer is the leader of one of the Sachakan factions - in fact, the leader of Savaras faction.